# find the average of numbers

Tags: java

A simple java program to input the name of student and find the average of marks of three subjects obtained by him

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;


class MyException extends Exception
{

    MyException(String s)
    {
        super(s);
    }
}

class Student 
{
    String name;

    String inputName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    void average(int [] a)
    {
        int d;

        if ((a.length)==3)
        {
            d = (a[0]+a[1]+a[2])/3;
            if (d>50)
                System.out.println(" Congratulations!!! "+name+ " 
                        you have passed the examination");
            else
            System.out.println(" Oops  " +name+"  Try Later!!");
        }
    }

public static void main(String x[]) throws IOException
{
    Student s= new Student();
    int args[] =new int[3];
    System.out.println("Enter name of the student:");
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    s.name=br.readLine();
    System.out.println("Name of the student is " +s.inputName().trim());
    System.out.println("Marks in Physics = ");
    args[0]=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine().trim());
    System.out.println("Marks in Chemistry = ");
    args[1]=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine().trim());
    System.out.println("Marks in Mathematics = ");
    args[2]=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine().trim());**$$**
    s.average(args);**##**
}
}
```

The code has no errors.The code is executing till **$$** step ,but the step indicated with **##** is not executing.I don't know why??

Comment: If the average is < 51 then nothing will be printed. That may be what is happening

Comment: Shouldn't the test be `if (d >= 50)`?

Comment: Is this homework? Also, be careful with arithmetic expressions. You're doing your calculations (including the division) using integers and only assign the result to a double. So an average of 2 and 1 would give you 1 instead of 1,5

Comment: Without knowing what you're inputting to the code, we can't help you. Also please read this: [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: @luketorjussen thanks for the prompt reply!!! yeah that was the only thing

Comment: @shree, no problem, but as Tom has said, be careful with dividing with integers

Comment: @Tom thanks but luke is right. no problem now!!

Comment: @shree quite the contrary. You do have a problem that is more serious and harder to notice than a crash or failure to print the values. Your results can be completely wrong.

Comment: for what are you printing stack trace if someone enter not 3 marks? Just print error message in `else` block

Comment: @Tom i have done the changes. thanks for warning!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @shree you're welcome. Just out of curiosity... how does it look now?

Comment: @alaster well i don't require that now. changed the code !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following is the output of a test run:

```
Enter name of the student:
hello
Name of the student is hello
Marks in Physics = 
52
Marks in Chemistry = 
52
Marks in Mathematics = 
52
 Congratulations!!! you have passed the examination
```

So, the method is actually executing but the reason you are not seeing any output is, just like others have pointed out, the following condition is not satisfied

```
if (d > 51)
```

Also it would be nice to add else part as follows:

```
if (d > 51)  {
    System.out.println("Congratulations!!! you have passed the examination");
} else {
    System.out.println("Sorry!!! you have failed the examination");
}
```

Comment: does this answer the question? or atleast a reason for why the error occured/occurs

Comment: condition is d should be greater than 50.and i have changed the code accordingly

Comment: @DavidKroukamp I think no issues now!!

Comment: No issues. lifted my downvotes, atleast now the answer is better explained thanks Bhesh Gurung and shree